# PostGIS ST_Distance discrepancy between GeogFromText and Point

Tags: postgis

```
SELECT t.coords, t2.coords,
  ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-115.83225 44.18711)'), ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-105.83225 54.18711)')) AS d1,
  ST_Distance(ST_Point(t.coords[2], t.coords[1]), ST_Point(t2.coords[2], t2.coords[1])) AS d2
FROM locations
INNER JOIN locations t2 ON t2.id = 1
WHERE t.id = 2;
```

`t.coords = "{44.18711,-115.83225}"` and `t2.coords = "{54.18711,-105.83225}"`

`d1` is returned as `1326899.86792105` and `d2` as `14.142135623731`.

Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have to cast the `ST_Point` into a `geography` type, then it works.